# An identity involving Gamma function and its derivative

Tags: soft-question, gamma-function

Reading on wikipedia's page about Gamma function I've read this interesting formula:

$$\Gamma^{(n)}(1)=(-1)^nn!\sum_{\pi \vdash n}\prod_{i=1}^r\frac {\zeta^*(a_i)}{k_i!a_i}$$

But I don't fully understand it: I know what the Zeta with the "$*$" means but I don't know what the symbol "$\vdash$" stands for...

Next Wikipedia says that $\pi=(a_1,\dots,a_1,\dots,a_r,\dots,a_r)$ where every $a_i$ is taken $k_i$ times but I don't know what partitions are and I don't get how $a_i$ and $k_i$ comes from...

Can someone please explain me what technique this formula uses and maybe do some examples on how to calculate the first terms ? Is there any other ways to write this relation that don't deal with partitions and so on?

Comment: Perhaps it means $\pi$ is an arbitrary partition of $n$.  That means $\pi$ is a vector of natural numbers whose sum is $n$.

Comment: Ok so suppose i take $n=5$, do I have to calculate all the partition of $n$ ? And then how should I proceed to get the result ? @GregoryGrant

Comment: Sounds like yes you need all partitions.  But there aren't that many, because order doesn't matter, so $(2,3)$ is the same as $(3,2)$.  Then for each partition just evaluate the product - you said you know what $\zeta^*$ means, because I don't.

Comment: Yes I don't have any problem with that, so if I got that right: $a_i$ is a number that appears in the partition of $n$ and $k_i$ is the number of time it appears right ? @GregoryGrant

Comment: Yes I believe that is correct.  So for $(1,1,1,2)$ you have $a_1=1$, $k_1=3$, $a_2=2$, $k_2=1$.

Comment: What is $\zeta^*$ anyway?  just out of curiosity.

Comment: The Riemann Zeta function but with its value at $1$ taken to be equal to the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$ @GregoryGrant

Comment: In that case, I don't think it would be very easy to evaluate $\zeta^*(a_i)$ for most values of $a_i$.  For example, I don't think $\zeta(3)$ is known in any closed form.